# Use 4 input boxes rather than 3 in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on my computing A level project. I am using tkinter to create a text input dialog box. I can make it work with 3 labels but I really need it to have 4, does anybody know if this is possible? And if so how?

Many thanks

EDIT: http://pastebin.com/7yx7eP51 This link has the code for creating the dialogue box. At the moment the 4th ones are commented out as was testing the other parts

Comment: Could you please show the relevant parts of the code as well? That will make it much easier to provide specific answers, thanks. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: yes it is possible. how ? create next label the same way you created previous. better show your code.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: thank you! completely missed that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is only about the specific code of the user, who shows no effort made to solve the problem him/herslf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was closing parenthesis:

```
root = Tk()

label1 = Label(root, text = "Dive number")
E1 = Entry(root, bd = 5)

label2 = Label(root, text = "Time in")
E2 = Entry(root, bd = 5)

label3 = Label(root, text = "Time out")
E3 = Entry(root, bd = 5)


label4 = Label(root, text = ("Max depth"))#--------------NEW--------------
E4 = Entry(root, bd = 5)

def getinfo():
    print (E1.get())
    print (E2.get())
    print (E3.get())
    print (E4.get())

submit = Button(root, text = "submit", command = getinfo)
label1.pack()
E1.pack()
label2.pack()
E2.pack()
label3.pack()
E3.pack()
label4.pack()
E4.pack()
submit.pack(side =BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Zetys. That has reduced the stress levels a lot lol